# Tsconfig Build:Argument for '--lib' option must be: 'es5'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

Attempting to build an angular 7 application in visual studio and receiving an exception regarding the tsconfig.json lib version.

Below is the current tsconfig.json

```html
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Build Error

```html
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Build:Argument for '--lib' option must be: 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es7', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'dom', 'dom.iterable', 'webworker', 'scripthost', 'es2015.core', 'es2015.collection', 'es2015.generator', 'es2015.iterable', 'es2015.promise', 'es2015.proxy', 'es2015.reflect', 'es2015.symbol', 'es2015.symbol.wellknown', 'es2016.array.include', 'es2017.object', 'es2017.sharedmemory', 'es2017.string' DocumentLibraryWeb C:\Users\Tim\Source\Repos\project-sparkle\Athena\DocumentLibraryWeb\tsc
```

Comment: What version of TypeScript do you have installed?

Comment: "typescript": "~3.2.2"

Answer (score 0):

## Debugging

```html
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Build:Argument for '--lib' option must be: 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es7', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'dom', 'dom.iterable', 'webworker', 'scripthost', 'es2015.core', 'es2015.collection', 'es2015.generator', 'es2015.iterable', 'es2015.promise', 'es2015.proxy', 'es2015.reflect', 'es2015.symbol', 'es2015.symbol.wellknown', 'es2016.array.include', 'es2017.object', 'es2017.sharedmemory', 'es2017.string' DocumentLibraryWeb C:\Users\Tim\Source\Repos\project-sparkle\Athena\DocumentLibraryWeb\tsc
```

`es2018` is not mentioned in this list. It is however a valid option in current TypeScript.

## Fix

TypeScript version being used by visual studio is clearly the wrong version.

Quickest fix, guaranteed to work, would be to do a vs reinstall / project reinitialisation.

Comment: Are you telling me to reinstall visual studio? Is there no way to change the typescript version in VS?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to compile by disabling the visual studio typescript compiler. To disable using the following:

Add the property true to a PropertyGroup in your csproj file (I added it under the Configuration label). This should disable all msbuild based TS compilation.

With this setting enabled you shouldn't need the tsconfig.json settings compileOnSave/buildOnSave.

If you are on an older version of Visual Studio (I had implicitly thought about VS 2017 or xproj with 2015), the property may be false.

Answer (score 0):

Check your typescript version.

For me issue was nested project with a nested package.json where typescript version was an old 1.
My script was running the build inside that folder